# Acumatica import scenario change default receipt to

Tags: acumatica

I created an data source 'CSV' that has 2 columns. receipt_to and inventory_id.
I want to change the on the warehouse details screen, the default receiving location to Main, from whatever it currently is.

I created an import scenario and tried to configure it multiple ways. I can't get it to work. Sometimes I receive an error that either the value "Main" or the field "Default Receipt To" doesnt exist. I don't understand the error because I am sure both the field (which I selected) and the value "Main" is a legitimate location

See image
[image: Import Scenario]

Answer (score 0):

Kyle, add "Warehouse" also in your input file. So, your input file must have InventoryID and Warehouse. and your import scenario must be like this.[image]